# I just want to delete one news each time, but I´m deleting more than one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a php file with a list of news that are coming from database.

And in each news I have a link to delete it, like this:

```
echo '<a id="'.$result_news['id_news'].'" class="j_newsdelete" href="#">Delete</a>';
```

And then I have my jQuery and AJAX to get id of my news and delete my news.

But my news is only deleted if the user clicks in "Yes" in a dialog modal that I make available.

```
<div class="delete_dialog">
    <div class="confirm">
        <p></p>
        <a href="#" id="delete">Yes</a>
        <a href="#" id="no">No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my delete is working fine when I delete each news, but... Im having a problem here.

**The problem Im having:**

When I click in "Delete", my dialog confirmation appears,

But If I click "No" in that moment the news is not deleted (so its working fine) and my confirmation dialog is closed...

But in the next moment if I click in "Delete" in other news and click "Yes" in my dialog confirmation, this news is deleted but also my news that I clicked "No" before is also deleted.

Can you please give me a help to try understand what is happening here?

My jQuery & Ajax

```
$('.content').on('click','.j_newsdelete',function(){
    var news_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.content .news li[id="'+ news_id +'"]').css('background','red');
    $('.delete_dialog p').text('Are you sure you want to remove this news?');
    $('.delete_dialog').fadeIn("slow",function(){
        $('.confirm').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $("a#no").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.confirm').fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("slow"); 
        });
        $('.content .news li[id="'+ news_id +'"]').css('background','#f5f5f5');
    });
    $("a#delete").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post(url,{action:'news_del',id: news_id},function(){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('.content .news li[id="'+ news_id +'"]').fadeOut("slow");
        },500);
        $('.confirm').fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast"); 
        });
    });
});
return false;
})
```

Comment: Why are you bind events inside another event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the events outside and put the variable outside also.

```
var news_id = null;

$("a#no").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.confirm').fadeOut("slow",function(){
        $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("slow"); 
    });
    $('.content .news li[id="'+ news_id +'"]').css('background','#f5f5f5');
    news_id = null;
});
$("a#delete").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!news_id) return;
    $.post(url,{action:'news_del',id: news_id},function(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $('.content .news li[id="'+ news_id +'"]').fadeOut("slow");
        },500);
        $('.confirm').fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast"); 
        });
    });
});

$('.content').on('click','.j_newsdelete',function(){
    news_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.content .news li[id="'+ news_id +'"]').css('background','red');
    $('.delete_dialog p').text('Are you sure you want to remove this news?');
    $('.delete_dialog').fadeIn("slow",function(){
        $('.confirm').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems to work. But Im deleting in my delete.js file new but also users, categories, etc etc. Its "correct"  to have a $(function(){...}); for each object(categories,news,etc) that Im removing like this?

Comment: @OzzC If you are doing the same stuff maybe you can make a function that decides what to do in each case. But if the function is very different, then you could keep different functions.

Comment: Thanks. I saw your code, and it seems to work, but now I come to computer to test it and its not working. With your code Im not deleting any news. When I click in some news I got my red background but the news is not deleted..And also if I click in "No" my background dont stay with color #f5f5f5.

Comment: @OzzC but is the dialog fading out?

Comment: Forget, it is working. I forget to do two things. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed your problem is due to the fact that you are assigning event handlers inside other event handlers, specifically you bind the yes/no click handlers every single time the original delete button is clicked.

Basically:

```
$('.content').on('click','.j_newsdelete',function(){
    ...
    $("a#no").click(function(event){
    ...
    });
    $("a#delete").click(function(event){
    ...
    });
 });
```

To demonstrate the problem better see this: http://jsfiddle.net/6p8mx7nd/

And a possible solution is to use a global variable for the clicked news item id: http://jsfiddle.net/6p8mx7nd/1/